# Difference between Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) and Debian with Cinnamon

Tags: debian, linux-mint

After reading the wikipedia article about LMDE<sup>1</sup> and also being about to refurbish a friend's laptop, I'm still wondering what the exact (major) difference between installing Debian with Cinnamon and installing LMDE would be.

In both cases one would have access to Debian's repositories and some additional Linux Mint packages (through LM's Software Manager). The latter includes proprietary software, artwork and the MintTools (I suppose).

Are there any other substantial differences e.g. with respect to performance, dependencies, proprietary software packages, release cycles...
More specific:

- LMDE won't be a rolling release any more as of 1/2016 but how would that affect me when using `apt-get` and the Software Manager alongside each other
- i.e. would `apt-get` get me only access to Debian's repositories in both cases?
- w.r.t. performance - are there different init daemons<sup>2</sup>?
- ..

If there are no differences - why is LM promoting it then as something different than Debian + LM desktop environment? Similar to the KDE project promoting a "KDEDE" distribution - which they're not.

DISCLAIMER:
It might be that I haven't yet fully grasped what exactly is set up when installing a desktop environment.

---

<sup>1 .. Linux Mint does not seem to provide much information [here](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php).</sup>

<sup>2 .. I've read for instance that Ubuntu is using a [different one](https://superuser.com/a/154347) compared to Debian resulting in slightly different boot times.</sup>

Comment: Related: [This older post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88369/125388) asked on "Difference between Debian 7.1 and Linux Mint 15 Debian"

Comment: @clearkimura thnx. OK, so there really is no difference except for the branches, it seems. I guess, my question is a dublicate then.

Comment: For generic information, refer to [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#Linux_Mint_Debian_Edition) about Linux Mint Debian Edition. This question should be limited to one issue when possible, because it has few issues mixed together.

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon is a desktop environment. You have a choice as to what GUI you want.

Here is a [link](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) for information,.

Cinnamon is an optional GUI to the standard one that ships.